# python socket connecting to different subnet/domain

Tags: python, sockets

Is it possible to connect to a different subnet or domain by python socket programming?

I want to make a script for sharing files with friends,, but currently I only know how to
connect within one LAN.

Comment: You create a socket object, and then you `socket.connect((hostname, port))`. Have you tried?

Comment: This works,, but I want to know how to do the same thing when the hostname is under some subnet, in which case I can't connect them directly I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in LAN, you should broadcast packets to discover each other.
and every peer should listen the port to receive broadcast.

It is discovery protocol, you can implement it by UDP socket.

Once two peer decide to communicate, they should create a TCP socket. Then, they can send data via TCP.
Or you can use HTTP, XML-RPC etc. to transfer data(not broadcast, TCP is not support broadcast).

---

```
#udp broadcast
import socket, time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)

while True:
    data = 'test'.encode()
    s.sendto(data, ('255.255.255.255', 1080))
    time.sleep(1)
```

---

```
#udp receive broadcast
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('', 1080))

while True:
    print(s.recv(1024))
```

Comment: Yeah, broadcast, that should be a good way.
So is there any way I can broadcast to all under another LAN?

Comment: @Jilin broadcast to another is complex. If there is not NAT, you can set fill hostid with 1 as dest ip to broadcast. But for NAT, You will need a server as proxy.

Comment: Still a lot to learn. thanks, at least I know how to handle it under one router now.